# Alternatives for Double Apostrophe for Postgresql queries?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I noticed a lot of pythonic replace functions being used prior to using psycopg2 to insert data into a database.  I understand that it is done to prevent the user from creating malformed sql queries.

Example:
`insert into users (name) values ('Hello''World');`
Which will store: `Hello'World` in the column.

My thought process is that they are only really doing this before inserting and I feel uneasy about it.

Example:

```
    s = "Hello'World"
    q = "insert into users (name) values ('{}');".format(s.replace("'", "''"))
    cursor.execute(q)
```

It feels off to me.  Part of me is thinking that I can still mess with `s` in such a way to get around this replace as it is the only thing stopping injection.  Yes, the arent using psycopg2 correctly because the second param is a list or dict of values correlating to the database entry.

It should say:

`cursor.execute("insert into users (name) values (%s);", ["Hello'World"])`

So i am trying to find a Proof of concept to do sql injection here as I dont think just double ticks isnt good *enough*.

Since this was python I am thinking of options, but i dont know how postgres works, if there is some sort of preprocessor used in strings etc.

Is there a way to pass a string which will get processed as s `'` without replace touching it?  I was looking into things like attempting to pass in unicode or something.  See if I can do something with unicode or chr to get it to process differently?

Has anyone else encountered this?  I am sitting in dbeaver as well as psycopg2/python to see if i can get a working sample working.

Comment: Good question!   I agree with you wholeheartedly -- why reinvent the wheel with manipulating the quotes when the psycopg2 library handles it well and is battle-tested?

Comment: Thanks @ChrisCurvey.  I hope someone knows a simple injection sample.  If it doesn't then maybe it is "valid" but not necessarily the best way.